# Массовая блокировка переходов на NGINX = http_referer

Tags: nginx

Нашел на вашем сайте инструкцию как блокировать переходы по имени домена. Возможно ли осуществлять блокировку по анкору?

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105799/nginx-block-from-referrer)

Answer (score 1):

Имеется в виду то, что после `#` в адресе?

Тогда нет. Анкор не передается на сервер, это чисто клиентский фрагмент. Его можно получить только через JavaScript в браузере.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2317523/9435985